# Is there a hash function to generate a hash with a given length?

Tags: security, hash, cryptography

Is there a function that generates a hash that has the exact lenght I want? I know that **MD5** always has 16 bytes. But I want to define the lenght of the resulting hash.

Example:

```
hash('Something', 2) = 'gn'
hash('Something', 5) = 'a5d92'
hash('Something', 20) = 'RYNSl7cMObkPuXCK1GhF'
```

When the length increases, the result should be more secure from duplicates.

Comment: Just use a good hash like SHA2 and truncate. If you need to support long outputs, plug together a hash and a stream cipher.

Comment: And you certainly don't want to use MD5 of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The upcoming **SHAKE256** (or SHAKE128 for a security level of 128bit instead of 256bit), a so called *extendable-output function* (XOF), is exactly what you are looking for. It will be defined alongside with SHA3. There is already a [draft  online](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/drafts/fips-202/fips_202_draft.pdf).

If you need an established solution now, follow CodesInChaos advice and truncate SHA512 if a maximum of 64byte is enough and otherwise seed a stream cipher with the output of a hash of the original data.

---

Technical disclaimer: After an output length of 512bit the "security against duplicates" (collision resistance) does not increase any more with longer output, as with SHAKE256 it has reached the maximum security level against collisions the primitive supports (256bit). (Note that because of the birthday paradox the security level of an ideal hash function with output length of n bit against collisions is only n/2 bit.) Any higher security level is pretty much meaningless anyway (probably 256bit is already an overkill) given that our solar system does not provide enough energy to even count from 0 to 2^256.

Please do not confuse "security levels" with key lengths: With symmetric algorithms one usually expects a security level equal to the key size, but with asymmetric algorithms the numbers are completely unrelated: A 512 bit RSA encryption scheme is far less secure than 128bit AES (i.e. 512bit RSA moduli can be factored by brute force already).

If a cryptographic primitive tries to achieve a "security level of n bits" it means that there are supposed to be no attacks against it that is faster than 2^n operations.

Answer (score 2):

[BLAKE2](https://blake2.net) can produce digests of any size between 1 and 64 bytes.

If you want a digest considered cryptographically secure, consider the [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) and what other algorithms use — e.g. SHA-1 uses 20 bytes and is considered insecure, SHA-2 uses 28/32/48/64 bytes and is generally considered secure.

If you just want to avoid accidental collisions, still consider the Birthday problem (above), but 16 or even 8 bytes might be considered sufficient depending on the application (see [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Probability_table)).

Comment: If I needed more than 64 bytes?